# AMD Support for Linux

Tags: 18.04, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I am running Ubuntu 18 on my PC and have a Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445] GPU that I would like to run in it.

From what information I got online this driver is not supported officially by `amdgpu-pro`. Can someone give any suggestions what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same Video Card (on FX7500 CPU), Lenovo Z50-75.

I installed Ubuntu Studio 20.04 (I suggest you upgrade as well) on Friday: the video card is recognized by the system, and I can run also and external screen connected via HDMI without any kind of issue (both laptop and external screen running at 1920x1080 - audio is working as well).

By default the "radeon" driver is installed; I forced the "amdgpu" one (with a video I found on the internet that tells you how to change GRUB) but found no improvements.

Browser scrolling seems a bit clumsy, but my system (installed on a USB 3.0 external HDD) is fast enough to record the guitar (via external cheap USB Audio Card) while applying real-time audio effects with about 10ms latency.

I hope my answer was useful.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful.

I wanted to install OpenCL with the GPU to use it for some Machine Learning but I will ask that as a seperate question.